# How to set cache=FALSE for a knitr markdown document and override code chunk settings?

Tags: r, knitr

I understand that I can use the `cache=TRUE` option to cache an R code chunk using R Markdown with `knitr`. E.g., It might look something like this:

````
```{r longanalysis, cache=TRUE}
for (i in 1:5000) {
    lm((i+1)~i)
}
```
````

And I realise that If I wanted to disable the cache for that analysis that I could change the option to `cache=FALSE` in the code chunk. However, if I have many R code chunks with caching enabled, this would require a careful find and replace operation.

#### Question

- **Is there a way of temporarily setting `cache=FALSE` for an entire R Markdown document?**

#### Comments

I've seen [this example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rmd) where the first line is. So I imagine this is a way of setting global setting, but I think local settings override global settings.

```
`r opts_chunk$set(fig.width=5, fig.height=5, fig.path='')`
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It seems the default is set to FALSE and local chunk options override the global options but one thing you could do is set the global options to cache by default by adding this to the top of your document

```
`r opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)`
```

Then for the sections you don't want cached ever you would explicitly set those sections to cache=FALSE.

Then if you want to set the whole document to not cache anything you could change the global option to FALSE and rerun it.

The problem is that if any of the chunk options are set to cache=TRUE then those will override the global setting and won't be rerun if you set the global option to FALSE.  So I think the only way to achieve what you want is to change the default to cache=TRUE, explicitly set chunks that you don't want cached to have cache=FALSE, and then you can switch the global option to FALSE to do what you want when the time occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I think I just solved my own problem. I got stuck on the idea that it had to be a setting. But really all that is required is to delete the contents of the cache folder.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim That would do it too.  I still prefer having everything cached by default though and as an added benefit the problem you had can be solved without having to navigate to the folder and deleting the cache folder.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give both ways a try. I'm new to caching. I guess there is a trade-off. How often do you change code chunks that have effects for already run chunks. How slow is the code. How often do you need to knit to HTML. etc.

Comment: True - but even if a chunk is cached if you make a change to it then it should be rerun.  The only thing I don't cache typically is loading packages because if you cache those calls then things get messed up.

Comment: I think Dason's solution is what one normally should do. The question boils down global vs local chunk options, and `opts_chunk$set()` is the answer. Removing the cache directory sounds brutal, although it also works :)

Answer (score 20):

#### Delete cache option

`knitr` creates a directory to store the cached objects. By default it is called `cache`.
To ensure that all analyses are run regardless of the code chunks `cache` setting, simply **delete the contents of the cache directory**.

Thus, in Rstudio on Linux

1. Go to menu `Tools - Shell` to open a console in the working directory containing the markdown file.
2. Enter the command `rm cache/*`

#### A basic workflow

This is my basic workflow at the moment

- If knitting is quick (e.g., less than 10 seconds), don't cache.
- If knitting is taking a while (e.g., more than 10 seconds), add `` `r opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)` `` to the R Markdown file.
- If caching is causing problems and knitting is relatively quick (e.g., under a few minutes), delete the entire cache.
- If caching is causing problems and knitting takes a long time (e.g., several minutes or hours), name R code chunks and use the [`dependson` option in knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/options). Naming  also permits selective deletion of named R code chunks in the cache directory.

Comment: `Tools` > `Shell` seems to open a console in the current working directory of the r interactive console. This can differ from the location of the directory containing the markdown file, which is where the cache is stored.

Answer (score 17):

Too late once you've already created the document, but for future documents you might want to consider using the fact that the parameters are evaluated by `knitr`.  This means you can have things like:

````
```{r data.loading.chunk1, cache = cachedata}
blah blah
```
blah blah

```{r model.fitting.chunk1, cache = cachemodels}
blah blah
```
````

Then at the top of the document I have something like:

````
```{r libraries.etc, echo=FALSE, results='hide', message=FALSE}
cachedata = TRUE
cachemodels = TRUE
```
````

Which then allows you to quickly turn on an off cacheing for large numbers of chunks at a time.